# The Sieve of Eratosthenes code in C

Tags: c, algorithm

The following program is to calculate the total of all primes less than 2 million by using The Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm. The sum should be equal to 142913828922 while it is coming 1179908154. What is the error in this code?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

#define LIMIT 2000000

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int i,j;
    int *primes;
    int z=1,sum;

    primes = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIMIT);

    for(i=2;i<LIMIT;i++)
        primes[i]=1;

    for(i=2;i<LIMIT;i++)
        if(primes[i])
            for(j=i;i*j<LIMIT;j++)
                primes[i*j]=0;

    for(i=2;i<LIMIT;i++)
        if(primes[i])
            sum+=i;

    printf("total = %ld",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When asking for help, it's best to go over what you tried and where you think your error might be.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging math in your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define sum as a 64bit integer

```
long long sum=0;
```

Otherwise it is a 32bit integer and the number overflows.

In hex:

```
hex(142913828922) = 0x214653f83a
hex(1179908154)   =   0x4653f83a
```

Comment: answer is still coming wrong : 142918024874

Comment: Also check that you set sum to 0 before doing the for loop